# help picking filesystem for data array with ssd caching

Tags: server, 18.04, ssd, raid

I was using unraid until I realised its not supposed to be a server os its supposed to be a nas os and thats why it wasnt working very well for me

in my system I have 4x 8tb HGST Deskstar NAS drives
and 2x intel 660p nvme ssd drives

the 4 drives are indevidually formatted with btrfs
one was unraids parity one is empty and two have data but the data can fit on one drive

What filesystem would you recommend I use so I can make an array with the two empty drives them rsync over the data from the two drives with data then grow the array with those two drives and also support using the two ssds for caching?

I was thinking of just using btrfs because my teacher said its the best one but I cant find any info about ssd caching with it

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go with ZFS

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/ZFS